# change value of text span in toggle

Tags: jquery

```
$('.post-content').each(function () {
    var count = $(this).children().length;
    if (count > 1) {
        $(this).append("<span class='more'>More</span>");
        sel = $(this).children('p').slice(2);
        sel.hide();
    }
});


$(".more").click(function () {
    more = $(this);
    sel = $(this).parent().children('p').slice(2);
    console.log($(this))
    sel.slideToggle(function () {
        more.text("More");
    }, function () {
        more.text("Less");
    });
});
```

This code works fine, except when I try to change the more/less. Should be more -> less -> more and I have more -> less -> less

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6TaU/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things to take note of 1. slideToggle() takes 1 complete callback 2. which will be executed for every element in `sel`. You need to execute a single callback function where you will toggle the text when all the slide operations are completed.

For toggling the text you can use the [.text(function)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) variant of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text), for executing a single callback after the you can use the [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise) returned by the animation.

```
$(".more").click(function () {
    var more = $(this);
    sel = $(this).parent().children('p').slice(2);
    sel.stop(true, true).slideToggle().promise().done(function () {
        more.text(function (_, text) {
            return text == "More" ? 'Less' : "More"
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j6APV/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

```
.slideToggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

The first parameter should be the duration, the second should be a callback. You need to explicitly check for the current content of `more` and base your decision on that.